# Does using calloc inside function, change the pointer passed as function argument

Tags: c

I do not understand why the second printf loop outputs different data than the first printf loop    that was done inside the function scope. Can it be that the pointer is changed somehow inside the function so that when it returns it returns a different value?

Output:

*First printf inside function:*
Parts TMP|01245 
Parts X|40001
Parts Y|98760

*Second printf outside function, in main:*
It returns jiberish and not the same as when printing inside the function.
I tried to fprintf so that I can quickly paste the results in here ,but then I received an uninformative call stack error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"

void ProtocolParse_Start(int *numParts,char **parts, char *str, const char* partsDelim )
{
  int partCount = strChrCount(str,'~');
  *numParts = partCount;

  parts = (char**)calloc(partCount,sizeof(char));
  char *tempPart;


  tempPart = strtok (str,partsDelim);
  parts[0] = (char*)calloc(strlen(tempPart),sizeof(char));
  strcpy(parts[0],tempPart);


  int i =1;
  for(; i < partCount; i++)
  {
      tempPart = strtok (NULL, partsDelim);
      parts[i] = (char*)calloc(strlen(tempPart),sizeof(char));
      strcpy(parts[i],tempPart);
  }

   i =0;
  for(; i < partCount; i++)
  {
      printf ("%Parts %s\n",parts[i]);
  }

}

void ProtocolParse_End(int numParts,char **parts)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < numParts; i++)
        free (parts[i]);

    free (parts);
}


int main()
{
    char proto[32] = "TMP|01245~X|40001~Y|98760~";

    char **parts;
    int numParts;
    ProtocolParse_Start(&numParts, parts,proto,"~");


     int i =0;
     for(; i < numParts; i++)
     {
          printf ("%Parts %s\n",parts[i]);
     }

    ProtocolParse_End(numParts,parts);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please shed some light onto my problem. Because I am not sure what I'm doing wrong ??

Comment: Removed C++ tag to avoid everyone telling you to use `std::string` since this is clearly C code.

Comment: Sorry for this, just quickly clicked tags that were auto suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment of `parts` inside the function has no effect on the `char **parts` from `main`. In order to modify it, you need to pass a pointer to `parts`, and add an extra level of indirection (yes, you'd get three asterisks now).

The code that partitions the data to strings is incorrect, too: you need to allocate an array of character pointers, and then copy each token into that array individually.

```
void ProtocolParse_Start(int *numParts, char ***parts, char *str, const char* partsDelim )
{
  int partCount = strChrCount(str,'~');
  *numParts = partCount;

  *parts = malloc(partCount * sizeof(char*));

  char *tempPart;
  tempPart = strtok (str,partsDelim);
  (*parts)[0] = malloc(strlen(tempPart)+1);
  strcpy((*parts)[0], tempPart);

  int i =1;
  for(; i < partCount; i++)
  {
      tempPart = strtok (NULL, partsDelim);
      (*parts)[i] = malloc(strlen(tempPart)+1);
      strcpy((*parts)[i],tempPart);
  }

  i =0;
  for(; i < partCount; i++) {
      printf ("%Parts %s\n", (*parts)[i]);
  }

}
```

I made three changes to your code:

- Replaced `calloc` with `malloc`: you initialize every element anyway, so there is no reason to zero-fill the block
- Removed casts in front of `malloc` - this is not necessary in C
- Added one to `strlen(tempPart)` - you need this for null terminated strings.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still a grasshopper :).The point of using malloc instead of calloc I understand. I just wrote it in this way so that when I move the code to an Mbed C++ project that I don't have to change it later on. I read that strtok returns the token and automatically null terminates it, but forgot to add the +1 when locating the size. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried your code, but when trying to do the third malloc: (*parts)[i] = malloc(strlen(tempPart)+1); where i is 1 it failed. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @DR. You are passing an address in the `ProtocolParse_Start(&numParts, &parts, proto,"~");` call, right?

Comment: @DR. The code works fine on ideone [link](http://ideone.com/vNiRi5). You need to fix the `%`s in front of `Parts`, though, because `printf` takes this as an invalid formatting character.

Comment: Silly me, was doing (*parts[0]) instead of (*parts)[0] Did not just want to copy over so retyped it. Sorry and  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are different mistakes:

When you pass a parameter to a function it is always copied.
You gave a `char **parts` and it is copied.

Inside the function you overwrite the copied input with the new address of the `calloc`ed pointer.

Consider an easier example:

```
void doSomething(int a){
  a=5;
}
///...
int b = 6;
doSomething(b);
```

When you call `doSomething(b)`, your b is not changed.
If you want it to be changed, you have to pass a pointer to `b`.

```
void doSomething(int* a){
  *a=5;
}
///...
int b = 6;
doSomething(&b);
```

The same is with your `char*`array.

You have `char** parts`in your main, that you want to be set to the allocated array.
so you have to pass its pointer. and write the obtained address to the dereferenced pointer.

The other big mistake is, that you gibe the wrong soze to the first `calloc`. It should be `sizeof(char*)`.

Your routine should start like this:

```
void ProtocolParse_Start(int *numParts,char ***parts, char *str, const char* partsDelim )
{
  int partCount = strChrCount(str,'~');
  *numParts = partCount;

  *parts = (char**)calloc(partCount,sizeof(char*));
  char *tempPart;
  //...
```

(all further accesses to parts in the function have to dereference parts)

and the call have to look like:

```
ProtocolParse_Start(&numParts, &parts,proto,"~");
```

Comment: I was under the impression that when passing a char pointer, that it is passed by reference. But it seems that it is passed by value from reading your answer ?

Comment: I do not understand why I should use sizeof(char*) instead of sizeof(char) like I did. Because sizeof(char*) does not necessarily  equal 8 bits or 1 byte, depending on whether it is running on 32 or 64-bit computer. So I was thought using sizeof(char) is correct because it would surely mean 1 byte ?